# Help with a limit problem

Tags: limits

Can anyone help me solve these two limits? I am learning limits on my own and I progress slowly.

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left ( \frac{1-3x}{1-2x} \right )^{\frac{-2x+1}{x}}$

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\tan( 2 x ) }$

Any help is welcome.

Comment: It shall be $\tan$ or something.

Comment: @notorious, Can you please check the first limit, Should it not be $x\to0?$

Comment: Is it  $x\to\infty$ or $x\to0$ in the first problem? If it is $0$, the limit can be gotten as in lab's answer. If it is $\infty$, the limit can be gotten as in my answer.

Comment: It is $x\to\infty$.

Comment: both ($x\to0$ and $x\to\infty$) are interesting problems, dealing with different aspects of limits of composite functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x^y$ is continuous near $x=\frac32$ and $y=-2$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1-3x}{1-2x}\right)^{\frac{-2x+1}{x}}
&=\left(\frac32\right)^{-2}\\
&=\frac49
\end{align}
$$
As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151/13854), $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan(x)}{x}=1$, and since $\frac1x$ is continuous near $x=1$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\tan(2x)}
&=\frac12\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{\tan(2x)}\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1-3x}{1-2x}-1=\frac{-x}{1-2x}$$

Use $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$

---

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\tan2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\cos2x\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\dfrac{\sin2x}{2x}}\cdot\frac12$$

Comment: @notorious, See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponential_as_Limit_of_Sequence

Comment: Dd you read the first problem correctly? The base tends to $\frac32$ and the exponent to $-2$. Ah, I see... $x$ is tending to $\infty$, not $0$.

Comment: @robjohn,  I think the limit should be $x\to0$